# In Opencart v 2.0.3.1 when order status update send a mail to Customer where this email function exist?

Tags: function, email, opencart

In Opencart v 2.0.3.1 when order status update send a mail to Customer where this email function exist ???
In V 1.5.5.3 Email function exist admin > model > sale > order.php
But i need version v 2.0.3.1 ???

Answer (score 1):

In opencart version 2.0.3.1, order status change through api.

Admin section is also used frontend order email functions. Email function exists in **catalog/model/checkout/order.php**